# Can my husband refuse to talk to my non-muslim mother?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim

I had an argument/fight with my non-muslim mother because I did not want to celebrate my birthday. After I told this argument to my husband he became so angry that he refuses to talk to my Mom and come to her house. Is this allowed, in light of the fact that muslims are not allowed to break blood relationships and have to treat parents with respect?

Facts that might be useful:

- I am a revert to Islam and my husband introduced me to it
- My mother has a hard time accepting my religion and we have arguments some times

Comment: Anger is forbidden in Islam.

Comment: Your mother is not his relative and she isn't a Muslim, what should hinder him from refusing to talk to her? It is certainly not a good nor wise act. But it is definitely permissible.